# Line Integral and area between curves

Tags: multivariable-calculus

What is the difference between Area between two curves and line integral and similarly the difference between volume between two surfaces and surface integral.

Can we reduce line integrals to area between two curves?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem